# Why is setTimeout not pausing the appropriate milliseconds in my jest tests?

Tags: asynchronous, jestjs

I'm playing around with the jest documentation on timer mocks to better understand how they work. When I run the below code, why are the setTimeout's not pausing? When I run this test, it immediately gives me test results even when I had set those gigantic millisecond values. For example 'b' prints immediately even when 500000000000 milliseconds has not passed.

timerGame-test.js

```js
test('calls the callback after 1 second', () => {
  const timerGame = require('../timerGame');
  const callback = jest.fn();
  timerGame(callback);

  // At this point in time, the callback should not have been called yet
 expect(callback).not.toBeCalled();
console.log('a ');
  // Fast-forward until all timers have been executed
  setTimeout(
      console.log('b'), 500000000000);
  
  // Now our callback should have been called!
 setTimeout(expect(callback).toBeCalled(),7000000);
  
});
```

timerGame.js

```js
// timerGame.js
'use strict';

function timerGame(callback) {
  console.log('Ready....go!');
  
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Time's up -- stop!");
    callback && callback();
  }, 10000000);
}

module.exports = timerGame;
```

Comment: You should return a Promise from `timerGame` and `await` that in your test

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` expects two arguments, first one being a function. When you call it like this:

```
setTimeout(console.log('b'), 500000000000);
```

`console.log('b')` is evaluated immediately and the first argument given to `setTimeout` is whatever is returned by `console.log('b')`, which is `undefined`.

This would work as you expect:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('b'); }, 500000000000);
```

EDIT: Note that in timerGame.js, the setTimeout is used correctly, and a function is given to it as the first argument.

Maybe this will clarify it to you, imagine you first store the *callback* function in a variable and then pass it to the `setTimeout` function, like this. This is essentially what happens in timerGame.js:

```
let logFunc = function() { 
    console.log("Time's up -- stop!");
}
// typeof(logFunc) == 'function'
setTimeout(logFunc, 50000);
```

Compare it with what you have earlier:

```
let badLogFunc = console.log('b'); 
// typeof(badLogFunc) == 'undefined'
setTimeout(badLogFunc, 50000);
```

Comment: hmm okay why doesn't "Time's up -- stop!" print then in timerGame.js? Shouldn't that be evaluated immediately too?

Comment: There, you give it an anonymous function as the first parameter. From inside that function, the console.log is called. It's called "callback". If you compare the two `setTimeout`s carefully, you can see that in timerGame.js the consol.log is wrapped inside a function. Google about JavaScript callbacks!

Comment: @user9650660 I updated my answer to illustrate the difference better.